# How do you write Data from a Spark Data Frame to Azure Application Insights from data bricks using python?

Tags: pyspark, databricks, azure-application-insights, open-telemetry, azure-monitoring

I have a spark data frame that has some reconciliation data and this data frame only gets created if reconciliation fails.

When this spark data frame does get created in databricks, I need to send the data in it to azure application insights from databricks.

```
try:
    # Check count of reconciliation Data Frame and send to Application Insights if count > 0, meaning there's one or more reconciliation error(s).
    if reconciliation_DF.count() > 0:
       reconciliation_DF_json = reconciliation_DF.toJSON().collect()   # Convert Data Frame to JSON
       reconciliation_DF_json = json.dumps(reconciliation_DF_json)    # Convert list of JSONs to string for logging

       # Some code here to write this "reconciliation_DF_json" data to Azure Application Insights???
       # This is where I am stuck.

    else:
         print("No reconciliation errors found")

except Exception as e:
    print("An error occurred: {}".format(e))
    raise
```

There seems to be a library, “Open Telemetry”, but the Microsoft documentation isn’t clear on how to use that for my scenario.

A python code example of how to do this with a data frame named "reconciliation_DF" would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I work on Azure Monitor's Python OpenTelemetry solutions. Let me know if this helps. Using the [azure-monitor-opentelemetry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/opentelemetry-enable?tabs=python) library, you can instrument common libraries and python logs via a single configure_azure_monitor() call. You can then use the native python logging library to sent traces to Application Insights:

```
configure_azure_monitor(connection_string=CONN_STR)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
try:
    # Check count of reconciliation Data Frame and send to Application Insights if count > 0, meaning there's one or more reconciliation error(s).
    if reconciliation_DF.count() > 0:
       reconciliation_DF_json = reconciliation_DF.toJSON().collect()   # Convert Data Frame to JSON
       reconciliation_DF_json = json.dumps(reconciliation_DF_json)    # Convert list of JSONs to string for logging

       logger.info(reconciliation_DF_json)

    else:
         print("No reconciliation errors found")

except Exception as e:
    print("An error occurred: {}".format(e))
    raise
```

Note that you can also set the connection string with an environment variable. There may be a few ways to do what you are trying to. Please, let me know if this fits your use case.

Comment: Btw I did have to make the following changes to your code to make this work:


AzureMonitorLogExporter(
      connection_string = "InstrumentationKey= xxxx"
    )

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

Please adjust your code accordingly.

Comment: You can also set the connection string via the APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING env var and configure_azure_monitor() will pull that automatically.

Comment: I wasn't able to find the "configure_azure_monitor()" it's even in the msdn documentation but when I tried to find it in the library it wasn't there. The edit to your code I made works though.

Comment: Please accept the edit I have provided for your answer as the `configure_azure_monitor()` is not available but the below way works:


`AzureMonitorLogExporter( connection_string = "InstrumentationKey= xxxx" ) 
logger = logging.getLogger(name) 
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
`